# If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two well-ordered sets, then $T_1 \cap T_2$ is also well-ordered.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two well-ordered sets, then $T_1  \cap T_2$ is also well-ordered.

I want to say yes, but I'm not sure how to explain that. If they are both well-ordered they both have smallest elements. I suppose the answer could be no, that if the elements that are in both form a new set that does not have a smallest.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 1) Misprint in the title. 2) The question should be contained in the body. 3) Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). 4) The question is not clear: is some ordering on $T_1\cap T_2$ given? is it supposed to be the restriction of the ordering on $T_1$ and/or the restriction of the ordering on $T_2$? 5) Please **review the definition** of a well-ordering. 6) Please remove the tag number-theory, and replace discrete-mathematics with order-theory.

Answer (score 3):

A set is called well-ordered if every non-empty subset has a smallest element. If $A$ and $B$ are well-ordered then their intersection $A\cap B$ is well-ordered because it is a subset of both $A$ and $B$. Any subset of $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A$ and thus has a smallest element.